# SQL Actual Execution Plan with Sort took high cost

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table named `DocumentItem` with `Id` column was clustered index (primary key).

Please see these two query strings:

- Query 1 (not use order by):

```
    select *
    from DocumentItem
    where (HistoryCreateDate >= '2019-09-04 05:00:00' AND HistoryCreateDate <= '2019-12-04 05:00:00') and ActNodeState>140100
```

**The result took: 00:00:09 with 168.357 rows.**

- Query 2 (used order by):

```
    select *
    from DocumentItem
    where (HistoryCreateDate >= '2019-09-04 05:00:00' AND HistoryCreateDate <= '2019-12-04 05:00:00') and ActNodeState>140100 order by Id
```

**The result took: 00:02:41 with 168.357 rows.**

Here is the actual execution plan:

[image]

Why it took so long in the 2nd query?

Comment: Could the Id field be considered a candidate for a clustered index?

Comment: Yes Ross Bush, this column is primary key with identity on.

Comment: Your row count estimates in your execution plan are waaaay off. Update your `STATISTICS` and maintain your indexes (consider rebuilding indexes once a week, e.g. at 3am on a Sunday).

Comment: Your results should be ordered the same in both queries, however, as mentioned above, (and there is most definitely something else going on here) you may need a plan to maintain your indexes and statistics.

Comment: Thank Dai and Ross Bush so much. I will try to apply as your suggestions.

Comment: @RossBush Nope - that is an incorrect statement. If the order of rows is important, then the query must have an order by clause. Without it, the order is undefined and the engine is free to return those rows in any order. That order can change depending on available resources and what is cached.

Comment: @Smor - I know order is never guaranteed without a specific order, however, I generally only see joins and groupings and window functions changing the order. This was against a single table so I would think the results would be ordered on the cluster as there is no other influence beside the where statement including a field within the same table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has decided that your index IX_HistoryCreateDate (not sure of the full name) is sufficiently selective that it will use it to find the rows that it needs. However, that index isn't sorted on the ID column. It does include the ID column already (whether you specified it or not) because it's the clustering key.

I'd suggest recreating your IX_HistoryCreateDate index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_HistoryCreateDate ON DocumentItem
( HistoryCreateDate, ID)
INCLUDE (ActNodeState);
```

And I think you'll be fine. It's still not going to be great and it will have to do a large number of lookups, because your query uses SELECT *. Do you really need all columns returned? If so, and you do this all the time, you might consider reclustering the table in the order that you need.